# React Redux Firebase check if value exist before dispatch

Tags: reactjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, react-redux

Not sure how to check if data exist using redux, anyone have a quick answer?

```
export function fetchName(name) {
    return dispatch => {

        const guestsRef = database.ref('/guest').set({
            name
        })
            .then(function (snapshot) {
                dispatch(setName({
                    name
                }));
            });
    }
}
```

This code just overwrites same entry and clears all data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const guestRef = database.ref('/guest');

guestRef.once('value', snapshot => {
    const guest = snapshot.val();

    if(!guest || !guest.name) {
        guestRef.set({ name });
    }
});
```

OR

```
try {
    const guest = (await database.ref('/guest').once('value')).val();

    if(guest == null) {
       const updates = { name };
       await database.ref('/guest').update(updates);
       //await database.ref('/guest').set({ name });
    }
} catch (error) {
    //error handling
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to abort a particular function you can `return false` at anytime.

```
export function fetchName(name) {
    return dispatch => {

        const guestsRef = database.ref('/guest').set({
            name
        })
            .then(function (snapshot) {

                if ( snashot ) { return false; }

                dispatch(setName({
                    name
                }));
            });
    }
}
```

This way you avoid invoking `dispatch` and overwritting your data.